# Erro com o comando de análise fatorial

Tags: r

O comando `factanal()` de análise fatorial mostra um mensagem de erro sem sentido.

Tenho que efetuar a análise fatorial, quero comparar os escores obtidos quando utilizo as soluções pela matriz de variância e a de correlação.

Aparece erro de falta de matriz X, porém ela está dentro do comando.

Segue base do R:

```
iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))

iris = cbind(iris[,(1:4)])
```

Segue comando executado e techo com erro:

```
mvscov <- factanal(iris, factors=1, covmat=var(iris), n.obs=150, rotation="none", scores="regression")

Error in factanal(iris, factors = 1, covmat = var(iris), n.obs = 150,  : 
  scores requeridos sem uma matriz 'x'

mvscor <- factanal(iris, factors=1, covmat=cor(iris), n.obs=150, rotation="none", scores="regression")

Error in factanal(iris, factors = 1, covmat = cor(iris), n.obs = 150,  : 
  scores requeridos sem uma matriz 'x'
```

Comment: Não tenho experiência no uso dessa função, mas analisando o help e o código fonte dá pra perceber que só pode utilizar `scores = "regression"` (ou `"Bartlett"`) se não passar um valor par a`covmat`. As seguintes alternativas funcionam: `factanal(iris2, factors=1, n.obs=150, rotation="none", scores="regression")` e `factanal(iris2, factors=1, covmat=var(iris), n.obs=150, rotation="none", scores="none")`. Tem certeza que nenhuma das duas é a correta para seu caso? Para este exemplo, ambos retornam o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece, você está tentando usar simultaneamente opções da função que não permitem isso...

Veja, todas os comandos abaixo produzem os mesmos resultados. Eles são modificações dos códigos postados por você:

```
# Uso a mesma base de dados. Mas bastava escrever isso, 
# sem utilizar o iris3
iris <- iris[, c(1:4)]
```

Se você informa um banco de dados apenas com variáveis quantitativas, isso já é suficiente para produzir a análise fatorial. No entanto, a princípio isso significa basicamente a matriz de *loadings* (com dimensão k *x* k). A opção *score*  permite que sejam salvos os scores fatoriais (com dimensão n *x* k).

```
factanal(iris, 
     factors=1, 
     rotation="none", 
     scores="regression")
```

Outra opção é informar uma fórmula e, ao mesmo tempo, um conjunto de dados no argumento _ data_. A expressão *~.* significa que vou utilizar todas as colunas do banco de dados.

```
factanal(x = ~ ., 
     data = iris,
     factors=1, 
     rotation="none", 
     scores="regression")
```

Por fim, ao invés de utilizar um banco de dados, você pode passar apenas uma matriz de variância-covariância ou correlação. No caso da matriz de var-cov, é necessário informar o número de observações. Porém, executando deste modo, você não pode usar a opção *score* (**aqui está a fonte do seu erro**), uma vez que os escores são combinações lineares produzidas a partir das observações de cada linha do banco de dados. Como não há banco de dados passado para a função, calcular o valor do(s) escore(s) individuais não será possível.

```
factanal(x = ~., 
     covmat = var(iris),
     n.obs = 150,
     factors=1, 
     rotation="none")
```